# Reordering svg dom with d3js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm using d3 to render an svg.  I have an array of objects, each with a color property, like so:

```
data = [{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'blue'}];
```

I have an update function to draw circles with those colors, like so:

```
function update(data) {
    var circle = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data, function(d) {return d.color})
        .enter()
        .append('circle').attr('r', 50)
        .attr('cx', function (d, i) {return 50 + (i * 50)}).attr('cy', 50)
        .attr('fill', function (d) {return d.color});
    circle.order();
}
```

My understanding is that the last line in the function, circle.order(), should reorder the nodes in the svg dom to match the order of the data.  However, I change the array order and call the update function again, and it doesn't seem to do anything.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/du7mh/

I need to control the dom order to bring certain elements to the foreground, since there's no z-index in svg.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to use the enter-exit-update selection.  See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) by Mike.  Or a cheats way would be to just `selectAll("circles").remove()` at the top of your update function in the fiddle you posted. There has been a place holder in the in svg 2.0 for the z-index method but I don't know if that's happened yet - see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/JCXKef_GRCQ) in google groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The append selection doesn't have anything in it after update has run once. Setting `circle` equal to the both current and new elements works:

```
function update(data) {
    var circle = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data, function(d) {return d.color});
    circle.enter()
        .append('circle').attr('r', 50)
        .attr('cx', function (d, i) {return 50 + (i * 50)}).attr('cy', 50)
        .attr('fill', function (d) {return d.color});
    circle.order();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/du7mh/3/

Comment: Woops, I guess it was just a chaining mishap!  Thanks for the help.